# knife ssh -P without password on command line

Tags: chef-infra, knife

Currently we use knife to run instructions on a bunch of servers. But we end up having to specify our passwords using -P "Password".

I was wondering if there's a way we can have the knife ssh take the password from a file more like "sshpass" does?

I don't like it when i have to type my password on the command line and anyone with a sudo access can later go in to see the history and get my password.

Comment: Is there a reason why not to use SSH keys based authentication?

Answer (score 3):

It is highly recommended that you use SSH keys instead of typing your password every time, once you have set up SSH access based on keys, you could use:

```
knife -i <IDENTITY_FILE> ....
```

Where:

> *-i IDENTITY_FILE, --identity-file IDENTIFY_FILE The SSH identity file used for authentication. Key-based authentication is recommended.*